# SPIM - Are register/memory values retained until SPIM is reinitialized?

Tags: assembly, mips, spim

So I'm turning in a project for class, and both parts of the program work.

However I noticed:

If I load the program (`load "p5a.mal"`), then execute it with `run`, it works.

If I type `run` a second time, type the same input, it shows behavior that indicates the variables declared in `.text` are retaining their values from the previous run.

An example of a variable being declared can be seen here:

```
#Used to store the word count in the given string (initialized to 0)
    wordcount:  .word       0
```

For example, if `wordcount` was 10 in the previous run, it outputs 20 in the second run.

Is this standard behavior of SPIM? Or am I not correctly zeroing out my variables?

I am aware SPIM has the "reinitialize" command, but should the second run just work *anyway* (without typing "reinitialize")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My TA responded to my email, and SPIM does need to be reinitialized (with the `reinitialize` command) in order for registers and memory locations to be reset.